# Split single line into multiple lines using delimiter as ;

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a requirement of breaking single line output into multiple lines using `;` as the delimiter. The input is generated by a shell script and looks like this:

```
REVOKE ALL ON XXXXXX_ABC_AAA FROM PUBLIC ; REVOKE ALL ON XBJE_XXXXX_ABC_AAA FROM PUBLIC ; REVOKE ALL ON XBJE_XXADTXXX_ABC_AAA FROM PUBLIC ; REVOKE ALL ON XBJE_XXVXXX_ABECC_AAA FROM PUBLIC ;
```

I need to split this to multiple lines like this:

```
REVOKE ALL ON XXXXXX_ABC_AAA FROM PUBLIC ;
REVOKE ALL ON XBJE_XXXXX_ABC_AAA FROM PUBLIC ;
REVOKE ALL ON XBJE_XXADTXXX_ABC_AAA FROM PUBLIC ;
REVOKE ALL ON XBJE_XXVXXX_ABECC_AAA FROM PUBLIC ;
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `sed` to convert `;` to `;\n`:

```
$ line="REVOKE ALL ON XXXXXX_ABC_AAA FROM PUBLIC ; REVOKE ALL ON XBJE_XXXXX_ABC_AAA FROM PUBLIC ; REVOKE ALL ON XBJE_XXADTXXX_ABC_AAA FROM PUBLIC ; REVOKE ALL ON XBJE_XXVXXX_ABECC_AAA FROM PUBLIC ;"

$ sed 's/; */;\n/g' <<< "$line"
REVOKE ALL ON XXXXXX_ABC_AAA FROM PUBLIC ;
REVOKE ALL ON XBJE_XXXXX_ABC_AAA FROM PUBLIC ;
REVOKE ALL ON XBJE_XXADTXXX_ABC_AAA FROM PUBLIC ;
REVOKE ALL ON XBJE_XXVXXX_ABECC_AAA FROM PUBLIC ;
```

So if your script is called `foo.sh`, you would do:

```
foo.sh | sed 's/;/;\n/g'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Terdon

Comment: You're welcome @ShamsulHassan. If one of the answers here solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept  it](//unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tr` and standard `sed`:

```bash
$ tr -s ';' '\n' <file | sed -e 's/^[[:blank:]]*//' -e 's/$/;/'
REVOKE ALL ON XXXXXX_ABC_AAA FROM PUBLIC ;
REVOKE ALL ON XBJE_XXXXX_ABC_AAA FROM PUBLIC ;
REVOKE ALL ON XBJE_XXADTXXX_ABC_AAA FROM PUBLIC ;
REVOKE ALL ON XBJE_XXVXXX_ABECC_AAA FROM PUBLIC ;
```

This will first replace all semi-colons with newlines, then trims any blanks off from the start of each generated line and adds a semi-colon to the end.

If your input is stored in a `bash` or `zsh` shell variable, use

```bash
printf '%s;\n' "${var//;/;$'\n'}" | sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//'
```

This will first replace all `;` with the same character, followed by a literal newline. It then trims the spaces off from the start of each generated line.

Comment: Thanks a lot it was helpful